# Understand how xreplace works

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to figure out how xreplace works. When I write

```
    from sympy import *
    my_list = [1234.5678, 22.333333]
    my_list.xreplace({n : round(n, 4) for n in my_list.atoms(Number)})
```

I get an error: *'list' object has no attribute 'xreplace'*. What did I write wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`xreplace` is a method of SymPy's objects. Your `my_list` is just an ordinary Python list, so it doesn't expose that method. What you can do it this:

```py
from sympy import *
# Tuple is the SymPy version of a python tuple
my_list = Tuple(1234.5678, 22.333333)
my_list.xreplace({n : round(n, 4) for n in my_list.atoms(Number)})
```